# TensorFlow ResourceExhaustedError when running a simple model on Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting a ResourceExhaustedError when running a simple model:

```py
model = models.Sequential([
  layers.Input(shape=(None, 1)),
  layers.Conv1D(padding='same', kernel_initializer='Orthogonal', filters=16, kernel_size=16, activation=None, strides=2),
  layers.Dropout(0.5),
  layers.Dense(units=80000),
])

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_waveforms_ds,
                    validation_data=validation_waveforms_ds,
                    epochs=100)
```

The error I get:

```
_________________________________________________________________
None
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-fae874124f81> in <module>()
     12 history = model.fit(train_waveforms_ds,
     13                     validation_data=validation_waveforms_ds,
---> 14                     epochs=EPOCHS)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[80000,80000] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node sequential_34/dense_34/Tensordot/MatMul (defined at <ipython-input-67-fae874124f81>:14) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_16700]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Here's a print of `model.summary()`

```
Model: "sequential_34"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_37 (Conv1D)           (None, None, 16)          272       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, None, 16)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_34 (Dense)             (None, None, 80000)       1360000   
=================================================================
Total params: 1,360,272
Trainable params: 1,360,272
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I'm running this on a Google Colab using the GPU runtime. When I run the same code in a Gooogle Colab using the TPU runtime I just get a crash.

I'm feeding `tf.data.Dataset`s into the model, so I don't think I can control the batch size...

Elements of a waveform dataset's x have shape (None, None, 40000), and elements of a waveform dataset's y have shape (None, None, 80000).

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do defining your input layer with that shape `layers.Input(shape=(None, 1))`? (i.e why is the first dimension `None`)

Comment: Because the input shape I have is `(None, 1, None)`

Comment: Do you have a range of what those `None` value can be in practice? TensorFlow is trying to allocate a `80000x80000` matrix which is roughly 6GB. Given that your network topology that would mean that the 2nd `None` dimension is set to `80000` in practice, which would allocate already a lot of memory, not surprisingly over the 12GB threshold of Google Collab. So, either your dataset has elements with a shape `None, 80000,80000` which won't fit, or you messed up in defining your network topology,

Comment: That could be the issue.. How can you tell it's trying to allocate a `80000x80000` matrix?

Comment: It's written in the traceback : `ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[80000,80000]`